# How to begin with salesforce certifications?

Tags: certification

I am new to sales force but I have heard great things about how awesome the salesforce platform is. I have been following the trails and will continue doing them.I have given myself time till August to get as many certifications of salesforce. The problems I am facing are 
1)I dont to where to go after finishing the trails to learn more?
2) I dont know what is the syllabus and where to study for the exams?
3) I dont know which exams to give and how?
Basically I need to break down my 6 months  time so as to get as many certifications possible and any help for that will be welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "exams to give"?

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked several times on stackexchange. You might want to look at the below links:

[How to study/prepare for the Salesforce Developer Certification](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/how-to-study-prepare-for-the-salesforce-developer-certification)

[Salesforce certified Administrator or Salesforce cetrified developer?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102174/salesforce-certified-administrator-or-salesforce-cetrified-developer)

[What to Study for 401 Developer Exam](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93332/what-to-study-for-401-developer-exam)

Recently there have been few changes to Salesforce certification program. So the best thing to refer for syllabus is to refer study guides for each of the certifications available on [Salesforce certification site](http://certification.salesforce.com/).

Answer (score 2):

The first resource you optate is Force.com Fundamentals. This is by far the most salutary resource for learning the platform. In order to go through this resource, you authentically need to establish a Developer Edition account.

On top of that, there are some good workbooks you can go through:

Force.com Workbook
Security Workbook
Analytics Workbook
Conclusively, you can check under the App Logic -> Point and Click section of the documentation Salesforce provides.

By far, the best way to study, is to utilize the platform. The test does not involve Visualforce or Apex, but you must understand the cogency-and-click functionality. It is best to have about 6 months of Salesforce experience afore endeavoring this exam.

Check  http://certification.salesforce.com/  for correct information regarding salesforce certifications and release notes.
Good fortuity!

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI ... I went through the trailhead tours for Admin Beginner and then took a practice test to discover that nowhere near enough information was there ... got a 30%.  Then I did the Admin Intermediate tour and got up to %40 without studying my notes ... but I know it covered the right stuff and if I study my notes I can bring it up to maybe pass, but even though it covered all the right material it was not deep enough.

So yeah ... trailhead doesn't go deep enough - though it is great for getting you familiar with the system.  I talked to some experienced Salesforce Admins and Devs and they made some recommendations ... mostly paid.  I will not repeat what those are though because then you won't believe me ... will think I'm an advertisment ... besides I'm not going to recommend something I haven't tried yet.

So just keep that in mind.  Trailhead is a great overview but doesn't go deep enough.

And those testimonials where people say as complete noobs studied X for a week then passed are either liars or barely passed and couldn't admin Salesforce to save their life.  Just sayin'.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 route in Salesforce certification to kick start
1) Admin Level
2) Developer level

**Admin Level** - You can start with "ADM201 Certification" and I am also concentrating on this one to obtain as my 1st certification. And then you can futher go on with higher level of certification on ADMIN.
**Study Guide** - http://certification.salesforce.com/app-builders

**Developer level** -   You can start with "Salesforce Platform App Builder" and I am also concentrating on this one to obtain as my 1st certification. And then you can futher go on with higher level of certification on Developer.
**Study Guide** - http://certification.salesforce.com/administrators

Also please use below link which will help to get idea more about certification
http://www.adminhero.com/beginners-guide-to-salesforce-certification/

Comment: Also check below video from Salesforce to Know more about new certification program since Sep 2015

https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=3&v=wM5Th-ComR4

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same process and recently passed the exam. I basically follow through a guide that has all the sections that are included in the exam, and real exam samples. You can find it here: [https://www.amazon.com/Definitive-Guide-passing-Salesforce-Certification-ebook/dp/B01H0Z954O/ref=sr_1_1?s=digital-text&ie=UTF8&qid=1466181214&sr=1-1&keywords=The+Definitive+Guide+to+passing+the+Salesforce+ADM+201+Certification+Exam%3A+All+resources+and+real+exam+examples+in+one+place](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01H0Z954O)